# splitting an exml file into smaller files

Tags: python

the xml file contains information about movies. how do i split the xml file into smaller files? ( so each small file is a separate movie)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details, here is a broad outline of a possible approach:

1. Parse the XML using a suitable library ([BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/2.) etc.)
2. Find the element corresponding to each movie. This can be done using a plain `findAll` or may require using an XPATH expression.
3. Pretty print the subtree starting corresponding to each movie element into separate files.

Of course a more detailed answer is not possible unless you post some sample XML and provide more details.